# How do I convert a string to a URI component?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, encode

I tried encodeURI and encodeURIComponent, seems those are not converting properly.

```
 sample : encodeURIComponent("�‡‰™©");
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Where's the data coming from?

Comment: What output is it giving you?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "How do I convert a string to a URI component?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's working to me.  [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WM9DD/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will need a js library similar to this one.

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html

Comment: thanks Dan-o, it's really useful.
Bu it seems utf-8 encode method result is not fully compatible with AdDB.Stream write text result using UTF-8 charset.
Check quotes when converting french-speaking text.